# I did these stripes using CSS linear gradients for background but they don't appear that crisp and clear. Neither on desktop nor on mobile screens

Tags: css, linear-gradients

The borders appear a bit pixelated on desktop and the edges/borders aren't as sharp as they should be on mobile screen. I wanted to use this as a background for some stuff. What can be done to fix this? Here's the link to my codepen -

https://codepen.io/abhishekakade/full/dKVJLR/

```css
body {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 95vh;
  width: 97vw;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(
    145deg,
    #333 0%,
    black 30%,
    yellow 30%,
    goldenrod 35%,
    black 35%,
    black 40%,
    yellow 40%,
    goldenrod 60%,
    #000 60%,
    #000 65%,
    yellow 65%,
    goldenrod 70%,
    black 70%,
    #333 100%
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply with [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JZOdqL).

```css
body {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 95vh;
  width: 97vw;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(145deg,
    #333 0%, black 29.9%,
    yellow 30.1%, goldenrod 34.9%,
    black 35.1%, black 39.9%,
    yellow 40.1%, goldenrod 59.9%,
    #000 60.1%, #000 64.9%,
    yellow 65.1%, goldenrod 69.9%,
    black 70.1%, #333 100%
  );
}
```

Comment: Of course you could tune better the values to fit your needs but the concept is the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked! And yeah instead of using x.1% for the second/next colors, using just x% gave crisper borders. Thanks for the suggestion :D

Comment: In that case, if you want to be pedantic, you should use (x + 0.05)% and (x - 0.05)%. :)
However, please note that the ideal thing should be working with absolute values (pixels), but I don't know if you can write something similar to `x% + 1px`.

Comment: The reason is that in this case you're not really interested in a gradient, you're interested in making smooth enough the transition between pixels. If you choose the delta as percentage, it can happen that the delta is smaller than a pixel (in a low resolution screen) thus that you don't have the smooth effect.

Comment: Hey, I just tried using up to 3 or 4 decimal points in %. But nothing makes those borders appear sharp on mobile devices. Even tried using media queries. It works really well on desktop though. And it works on mobile devices when I switch to desktop view too. Although I'm trying everything on just codepen right now. Will try GitHub pages once and will let you know here if it works somehow (not really sure). Thanks for your help so far. I really appreciate it :)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a native speaker, so I want to be sure that I understood well what you say. You're saying that with my code you've solved the pixelated effect but now you have a sharp effect on desktop view (both in mobile and pc) and a non-sharp effect on mobile view. I'm right?

Comment: Yes, kind of. Your code solved the issue on desktop/large screens but for some reason, the mobile devices still show those borders as blurred (and not sharp/crisp/clear as I want them to be). But when I switch to desktop view on the same mobile chrome browser, it looks sharp/clear again. If you can, please [check this link](https://codepen.io/abhishekakade/full/pKpmWB/) on your mobile browser and then switch to desktop view on that same browser. You will understand what I'm saying. By the way, I'm not a native speaker either lol. I'm from India.

Comment: I thought that almost all Indians were bilinguals due to historical reasons. Anyway, I checked through crossbrowsertesting and I understood what you mean. Have you tried on an actual smartphone if there are differences? anyway, I really think that this should be implemented with absolute pixels but I think that percentage and absolute values cannot be mixed in this case. Thus, you should first check the dimension of your screen and then use the absolute values accordly.

Comment: Yes, you are right about that. % and pixels cannot be mixed. By the way, it seems like it's an **issue with Chrome for Android** because Firefox (on Android) gives those sharp and crisp borders that I was trying to achieve on mobile devices and with the same code. And thanks a ton for all your help man. I really appreciate it. Thanks again :)

Comment: You're welcome. I'm sorry that I can't be more helpful but the reality is that I don't code in CSS for 2-3 years. I just googled _how to draw beatiful CSS gradient__ and read the first 3 results. :)